# Count column values in SSRS, VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

How to create selected value count in ssrs(Expresion). In my table I want "P"(selected value) count in column field.. Could someone guide me. Thank You....

[image]

**Table1:**

| 02-12-2022 | 03-12-2022 | 04-12-2022 | 05-12-2022 | 06-12-2022 | 08-12-2022 | Presentdays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P | P | A | P | P | P | 5 |

Comment: I don't understand your question, would you clarify whatr you want counted, give us sample data, and show desired output?

Comment: @RobertSheahan, In matrix table I need columns count. I need column Expression. I'm not figure it out how to do that. Thanks for responding...

Comment: @RobertSheahan, I tried this expression "=count(Fields!Table1.Value= "P",1,0)"

Comment: Is the sample data actually how it comes out of your dataset query (I hope not) or are you using a matrix to pivot the data? We need to see the data from the query results

Comment: @AlanSchofield, I attached Image of output..

Comment: =COUNT(IIF(Fields!INAM.Value="P" and Fields!OUTPM.Value="P",0,0)) This expression not showing all records..

Comment: Thats not your dataset output is it? Do you actually have columns in a database table for each date!?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!DateObs.Value)
```

I first created a sample dataset

```
with cteSampleData as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        (CONVERT(DATE,'2022-11-15'),'Red', 3)
        , ('2022-11-15','Blue', 2), ('2022-11-15','Green', 4)
        , ('2022-11-16','Red', 1), ('2022-11-16','Blue', 4), ('2022-11-16','Green', 2)
        , ('2022-11-17','Red', 2), ('2022-11-17','Blue', 1)
        , ('2022-11-18','Red', 4), ('2022-11-18','Blue', 3), ('2022-11-18','Green', 1)
        , ('2022-11-19','Red', 5), ('2022-11-19','Green', 3)
    ) as Samp(DateObs, ColorObs, ColorCount)
)
SELECT * 
FROM cteSampleData as S
WHERE DateObs < '2022-11-20'
```

| DateObs | ColorObs | ColorCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-15 | Red | 3 |
| 2022-11-15 | Blue | 2 |
| 2022-11-15 | Green | 4 |
| 2022-11-16 | Red | 1 |
| 2022-11-16 | Blue | 4 |
| 2022-11-16 | Green | 2 |
| 2022-11-17 | Red | 2 |
| 2022-11-17 | Blue | 1 |
| 2022-11-18 | Red | 4 |
| 2022-11-18 | Blue | 3 |
| 2022-11-18 | Green | 1 |
| 2022-11-19 | Red | 5 |
| 2022-11-19 | Green | 3 |

Then I created a report with a matrix using it
[image]

Note that the CountDistinct in the header gives the total columns (of just the dates) and in the Details row gives the count for that value.

Comment: Could you tell me How can we add two data fields. I tried this "=count(IIF(Fields!INAM.Value = "P" and Fields!OUTPM.Value ="P", 1, nothing))" second field not counting... Thanks....

Comment: Again, I am confused regarding what you want @bush, we can certainly add fields but we need to know what your data looks like. Would you please post a sample of your data as it is stored in SQL? Ideally take my `with cteSampleData ...` block and modify it to give us your data so we can experiment with it.

Comment: @bush - use `SUM(IIF(BLAH BLAH , 1, 0))`

Comment: @HannoverFist, I want add two different column fields, I tried  this code for count "P" values how can i do that.
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!INAM.Value="P" and Fields!OUTPM.Value="P",0,0))

Comment: You can't use count, that will just count every results of your IIF (which by the way will always be 0 as you have that for the true and false parts). As Hannover suggested, you need to SUM the IIF. You IIF shoudl return a 1 for the things you want to count and a 0 for the things you don't want, then sum these.